# JQuery toggle on li causing other li to bounce

Tags: jquery

Hi I am making a information dropdown that uses a JQuery toggle. When I click on one to open the toggle div beneath it it causes the other li to bounce down then pop back into place. I want them to remain stationary.

I added an absolute position but then that removes it from the flow and does not push the lower divs down when the toggle div opens. The toggle div then just covers other divs below it.

Here is my JQuery:

```
var open = $('.open'),
a = $('ul').find('a');

console.log(a.hasClass('active'));

open.click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this),
    speed = 500;
if($this.hasClass('active') === true) {
    $this.removeClass('active').next('.box').slideUp(speed);
} else if(a.hasClass('active') == false) {
    $this.addClass('active').next('.box').slideDown(speed);
} else {
    a.removeClass('active').next('.box').slideUp(speed);
    $this.addClass('active').next('.box').delay(speed).slideDown(speed);
}

});

})(jQuery);
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div class="grid_12 omega boxes">
    <ul>
        <li id="monday"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="open"><img src="wp-content/themes/English42/img/mon.svg"></a><div class="box" >THIS IS THE TOGGLE DIV1</div></li>
        <li id="tuesday"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="open"><img src="wp-content/themes/English42/img/mon.svg"></a><div class="box">THIS IS THE TOGGLE DIV2</div></li>
        <li id="wednesday"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="open"><img src="wp-content/themes/English42/img/mon.svg"></a><div class="box">THIS IS THE TOGGLE DIV3</div></li>
        <li id="thursday"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="open"><img src="wp-content/themes/English42/img/mon.svg"></a><div class="box">THIS IS THE TOGGLE DIV4</div></li>
        <li id="friday"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="open"><img src="wp-content/themes/English42/img/mon.svg"></a><div class="box">THIS IS THE TOGGLE DIV5</div></li>
        <li id="saturday"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="open"><img src="wp-content/themes/English42/img/mon.svg"></a><div class="box">THIS IS THE TOGGLE DIV6</div></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Could you create a [FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/) sample. It's not clear, what you mean

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q7hh381r/

Comment: for some reason it is working just fine in FIDDLE

Comment: Ok, now the FIDDLE is working how it works on my site.

Comment: should it be like this? http://jsfiddle.net/chr7gvqs/

Comment: No, I want the boxes to go straight across but because theyre inline the toggled div comes "before" the next one, pushing everything else in the ul down.